# Posting a message associated with place using coordinates in Facebook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, coordinates, facebook-fql

I have the following coordinates:
latitude=59.427277
longitude=24.750971

I'd like to make a post to the user wall with location included, but I only have the coordinates.

[Facebook documentation has a place parameter in "post" table](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/), but i can't figure out how can i make a post with place when i only have the coordinates. It says that "object containing id and name of Page associated with this location" but i found no a way to associate my coordinates with a location. I cannot search from page table with coordinates because those fields ain't indexable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to lookup a place that is already registered on Facebook by using the search Graph path like this `https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=searchterm&type=place&center=34,-117&distance=10000&access_token=APP_ACCESS_TOKEN`

This will return a JSON object with places found for your search terms (including the ID of the place).

Comment: Is there a way to search for cities? That search didn't seem to return cities.

Comment: The search returns places for a location defined by latitude/longitude (see center parameter). As far as I know there is no other way to search for places.

Comment: Thanks, flagging it as an answer because it is the closest you can get with facebook.